# Simplify or Optimize Lambda Expressions Calculations for Extensive Use in Python

Tags: python, optimization, time, lambda, simplify

The lambda expression I have is an expression of 1 variable (x) but contains many matrix multiplications and matrix powers.

In addition, I called this lambda expressions in nested loops with huge number of iterations.

The following is my lambda expression.
M is a matrix and bk is a vector.

```
func = lambda x: bk.T.dot(matrix_power(M-x*eye(dim), -2)).dot(bk)[0,0] - 1
```

My question is whether there is a method to simplify the expression itself by executing the multiplications and powers once and **reach simplified expression** in terms of the one variable (x).

Then use this simplified expression many times by just substituting the value of x in it.

Comment: problem is that the `x` is embedded very deeply in the expression, so simplication is difficult. Maybe create a temp variable to store the result of transposed `bk`, but that's not a lot of optimization.

Comment: Isn't it possible to simplify this expression throught Sympy and then compute the simplified expression ?

Comment: @C.LECLERC kindly explain more what you meaan

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I made this modification but its somehow minor modification.
I think I should separate the inv(M - x*eye) in a separate lambda expression an calculate it once then square it.

Comment: For what it's worth, assigning a lambda like this violates PEP8.  On top of that, this might look a lot more clear if it wasn't condensed into one line.

Comment: I thought you could use Sympy's simplification functionnalities (see http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/simplification.html) to identify equivalent but simplified expression of your lambda. Then use it in your nested loops. Warning : It may be stupid.